# Migration to Mysql Connector Jar 5.1.27

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have just replaced my mysql connector jar 3.1.12 to 5.1.27. 
and getting error

> You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to the Statement.executeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement().

I got the solution that i should use

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

instead

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
```

The main problem is how can I replace this in whole project and is there any method to set it globally?

Is there any other Issues with 5.1.27 version which I should keep in mind?

Answer (score 2):

This defect is already raised to MYSQL team and they have fixed this issue in version 5.1.8. But this issue still exists for latest versions. So far this has not fixed. 
Please refer the below link for more info -

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41448

Connector J 5.1.8  - Working
Connector J 5.1.10 - Not Working
Connector J 5.1.18 - Not Working
Connector J 5.1.21 - Not Working