# MySQL connector issues

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, mysql-connector

I am facing a problem where I get certain error if change MySQL connector Jar version.
My code was finely running on JBoss version 4.0.4.GA.
Then I upgraded JBoss to Wildfly with connector jar version mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin, and did not made any changes to the code which was running well.
Now whenever I add some new row I get an error saying that Generated keys not requested.

`You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement().`

Earlier I thought this may be because of server(JBoss) upgrade issue. And I started adding `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to `connection.prepareStatement()`, in every code. But then I realize after reading this thread [Migration to Mysql Connector Jar 5.1.27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122075/migration-to-mysql-connector-jar-5-1-27) its not a JBoss  upgrade problem rather it is mysql connector version that causes this error.
Can any one point me out which version of mysql connector should I use to stop these errors. Because it is very difficult to add `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` in number of files.

Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please give me some insight on this ?

Comment: Can any one tell me should I go with adding `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` in every file OR is there any other way to get rid off this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: there's a few ways to tell the driver to return generated keys

1. Connection.prepareStatement(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)
2. Connection.prepareStatement(String sql, int[] columnIndexes)
3. Connection.prepareStatement(String sql, String[] columnNames)
4. Statement.executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)
5. Statement.executeUpdate(String sql, int[] columnIndexes)
6. Statement.executeUpdate(String sql, String[] columnNames)

From the javadoc for `Connection.prepareStatement(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)`

> Creates a default PreparedStatement object that has the capability to retrieve auto-generated keys. The given constant tells the driver whether it should make auto-generated keys available for retrieval. This parameter is ignored if the SQL statement is not an INSERT statement, or an SQL statement able to return auto-generated keys (the list of such statements is vendor-specific).

Unfortunately the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)) is not clear about what happens when you call `Connection.prepareStatement(String sql)`.

As far as I can tell, passing `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` (or the column names/indexes) guarantees that `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` will return a value. If you don't explicitly request it there's no guarantee that `getGeneratedKeys()` will return the values(s).

In short, to be compliant with the JDBC specification, you should always use one of the methods above if you intend on calling `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`

Comment: if I call `Connection.prepareStatement(String sql)` then is this called illegal usage of JDBC ?

Comment: No, it's not... and 99% of the time you can happily use this method. But, if you want `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` to return a value then you should (must?) use one of the methods I mention above.

Comment: Actually problem is my code was running very well before i upgrade to JBoss. Then I just upgraded it to wildfly and using driver `mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin` it failed with these sort of errors. I mean to ask is this happened because of connector driver ?

Comment: This is NOT caused by a jboss upgrade and it is almost 100% certain that it's caused by the driver upgrade. I think you were just lucky before getting results from `getGeneratedKeys()` without explicitly specifying `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, you should NEVER rely on this undocumented behaviour. I feel that the new driver version is doing the correct thing by throwing the exception. Fix the code and move on!

Comment: Thanks a lot Lance. You made my doubt clear. It was almost eating my brain wondering what wrong went, without touching single piece code how does it throws an exception. But you helped me in making thoughts clear enough.